# How to remove carpet tape from flooring?

Tags: cleaning, carpet, removal, taping

I used [Scotch Carpet Tape for Vinyl, Ceramic, and Hardwood](http://products3.3m.com/catalog/ca/en001/home_leisure/-/node_GSYFTL51NDgs/root_GST1T4S9TCgv/vroot_GSHCV1ZFXKge/bgel_GS3Q876XDGbl/gvel_PJDS4KCMV4gl/theme_ca_en_homeleisure_3_0/command_AbcPageHandler/output_html). I've since removed the rugs, but the tape is stuck to the floor now.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score -1):

Goof Off or WD-40 works great! Available at any hardware or grocery store.

http://www.goofoffproducts.com/